# WPF Translating a rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Window_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation rightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

    rightAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    rightAnimation.From = 0;
    rightAnimation.To = 200;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(rightAnimation , rect1);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rightAnimation, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", new DependencyProperty[]{UIElement.RenderTransformProperty, TranslateTransform.XProperty}));
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.AccelerationRatio = 0.8;

    sb.Children.Add(rightAnimation);

    sb.Begin();

}
```

I want to accelerate the rect1 to the right.. When i run it nothing happens.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. Does `rect1` already have a `RenderTransform`? The animation won't create one if it does not exist.

Comment: All i did was use expression blend to drag drop a rectangle element into the grid and fire up a mouseenter event of the Window and i edited the code behind using visual studio

Comment: My comment was supposed to imply the solution if you answer it with 'yes'. So just add a transform (either in code or in XAML).

Comment: Modify your XAML in expression blend and add `            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>` to your recangle.

Comment: How do i do it in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TransformGroup` to animate all transform types.

```
        DoubleAnimation rightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

        rightAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        rightAnimation.From = 0;

        rightAnimation.To = 200;

        TransformGroup transGroup = new TransformGroup();
        transGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform());
        rect1.RenderTransform = transGroup;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(rightAnimation, rect1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rightAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].X"));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.AccelerationRatio = 0.8;
        sb.Children.Add(rightAnimation);
        sb.Begin();
```